# Word formatting only applying to every other page

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I am creating a large document with a new list style created linked to heading styles to handle the formatting. I have created all my section headers and applied the appropriate heading styles, however, the formatting is only applied correctly on every other page. Pages where the formatting is not correctly applied results in all headers being left bound. If I try to increase the indentation, it cycles through the heading styles but does not move the text.

Thanks for your help

Formatting error https://ibb.co/iMqAVf

List style https://ibb.co/hJLAVf

Answer (score 0):

On Word, click to open a header or footer.

Open the **Header Footer Design** tab

Uncheck **Different Odd & Even Pages**.